# How to use HTTP request to retrieve data from Laravel API?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, api, xmlhttprequest

I am currently learning the Laravel API, and have been developed a very simple API that retrieves data from the database by simply entering 127.0.0.1:8000/api/XXX to the browser, however, when I tried to use ajax call to get data from the exact same url, the ajax always showed that the HTTP request was failed, the ajax codes I used are following:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "127.0.0.1:8000/api/XXX",
    success: function(data) {
      let response = JSON.parse(data);
      displayResult(response, 1);
    }
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
```

And this code always resulted in `alert("error");`, therefore I am wondering that maybe there are some Routes needed to be written in order to let the API properly processes HTTP request? I have already defined a route in routes\api.php:

```
Route::apiResource('XXX', 'XXXController');
```

PS: when entering the API URL to the browser, it worked fine, it went wrong when doing an ajax call with the API URL.

### Edit

These are the errors I got from the browser console after I used `function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` to catch the errors

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
    at Object.send (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:79420)
    at Function.ajax (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:77118)
    at retrieveAllBooks (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/api-query.js:25:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/api-query.js:10:7)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:41772)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:39791)
```

I am not exactly sure why it is an invalid URL, since if I copy and paste this link to browser, nothing goes wrong...

Comment: Can you check your log and see if anything there?

Comment: I mean the laravel's error log. Your javascript run the `fail()` part means that the server return status code other than `200`. Check that log and see which error(s) come from the ajax request will help you solve the issue. If you still can't solve, post the log here so we can help you.

Comment: Laravel log? Nothing there, let me run more ajax call, see if any errors are logged

Comment: Actually, there is still nothing there even if I ran the ajax multiple times...

Comment: Open your browsers console, then select network tab. Retry. Then press the url highlighted in red (since there was an error) and select preview to see exactly what went wrong.

Comment: You need to slightly modify your `fail()` call and get better information from [jqXHR, textStatus and errorThrown](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR). Use a `function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}` function call instead of just `alert()`. Then properly do `console.log` to review those callback arguments.

Comment: I have gotten errors saying that URL is invalid by using what you said....  Not so sure why that happened

Comment: Try adding `http://` ...

Comment: well....... adding `http://` actually solved the problem... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Actually the solution is simple, just add http:// to the url.